# как в массив добавить одну и ту же переменную js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть :

```
<div class="token_inner"><div class="new_lang">Wow</div></div>
<div class="token_inner"><div class="new_lang">Haha</div></div>
<div class="token_inner"><div class="new_lang">Cool!</div></div>
```

Как мне соответственно вставить в массив содержимое .new_lang, а потом из этого массива вытащить строчку ? 
Типа того arr = ['Wow','Haha','Cool!'] => sting = (Wow,Haha,Cool!)

Comment: `let arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('.new_lang')].map(el => el.textContent)`

Comment: Спасибо, на джава скрипте тоже желательно знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];
$('.new_lang').each(function(idx, el) {
  arr.push($(el).html());
})
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="token_inner"><div class="new_lang">Wow</div></div>
<div class="token_inner"><div class="new_lang">Haha</div></div>
<div class="token_inner"><div class="new_lang">Cool!</div></div>
```

остаётся вопрос - зачем...

Comment: Спасибо, просто это пример, когда пользователь выбирает значение из option, это значение показывается как тэг. Типа такой input с выбором тэгов. Но проблема в том, что пользователь может изменить содержимое тэга, и в базу данных отправиться уже измененная переменная, а мне надо бы сохранить значения в массиве